# Check Portable Executable (PE) file for COM signature

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, inproc

I need to programatically check arbitrary Dlls to see whether they are inproc COM servers. In other words, can they be registered on the current system using regsvr32 / DllRegisterServer.

Short of [Andy's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2681468/938668) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2681313/938668) question, is there a way to figure out the needed without having to:

- Load the library and check for DllRegisterServer/DllUnregisterServer exports.
- Attempt registration with regsvr32 while catching exceptions?

There must be something in the PE format that indicates the needed. My assumption is that 'regsvr32' already does this internally. Would appreciate any input.

Comment: You don't have to load the dll using LoadLibrary(Ex) to check exported functions. There are other ways, you could parse the PE format and the export table. Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/133747/Checking-for-exported-symbols-functions-in-a-DLL-w

Comment: Maybe the ImageHlp functions ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only thing that makes a DLL a COM object is that it exports `DllGetClassObject`. The only thing that makes it registerable is that it exports `DllRegisterServer`.

Comment: Just to clarify, if both conditions are met, target is COM, otherwise not. No combinations in between?

Comment: Close. This suggestion is the closest thing to what you're asking for, but a COM DLL that is implemented in .NET will implement neither. The other side of that coin is that .NET COM DLLs cannot be registered via RegSvr.exe