# Watcher app that restarts process if it stops, hangs or isn't responsive

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, process, system.diagnostics

I'm using a poorly developed app that keeps restarting because of memory leaks or other random errors that do not repeat if restarted. I do not have access to the code and can't fix it.

I've developed a c# app that manages restarts and keeps the program running if it just stops, but how do I identify a hang (or when it crashed but a windows error message keeps it "running").

I could use `System.Diagnostics` to detect if CPU time delta is 0 in 60 seconds time (as the process is usually at 25-30s, ~50%cpu usage), but this can cause unwanted restarts when the process idles for resources (as it has a query-intensive step that can last between 10min and 2hours).

So how can I detect if program is waiting for mssql query or network resources, and/or how can I detect and implement something like this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373347.aspx?

here is a simplified sample of what I use:

```
        //every 60 seconds

        Process[] procs;
        procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(appName);
        List<int> pidsRunning = new List<int>();

        foreach(Process p in procs){
             pidsRunning.add(p.id);                 
             //other gathering of data and command line arguments
        }

        foreach(int pid in pidsLast){
             if(!pidsRunning.Contains(pid)){
                  //do stuff if not running
             }
        }

        pidsRunning = pidsLast;
```

## UPDATE

---

I have tried to use `p.responding` but in my case it is set to **true** even though the application has throwned an error:

```
Program has stopped responding
details:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: app.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    500efec6
  Fault Module Name:    mshtml.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.0.7600.17267
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5131882e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00429796
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

here is the process object for the same program:

```
-       p   {System.Diagnostics.Process (app)}  System.Diagnostics.Process
-       base    {System.Diagnostics.Process (app)}  System.ComponentModel.Component {System.Diagnostics.Process}
+       base    {System.Diagnostics.Process (app)}  System.MarshalByRefObject {System.Diagnostics.Process}
        Container   null    System.ComponentModel.IContainer
        Site    null    System.ComponentModel.ISite
+       Static members      
+       Non-Public members      
        BasePriority    8   int
        EnableRaisingEvents false   bool
+       ExitCode    'p.ExitCode' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  int {System.InvalidOperationException}
+       ExitTime    'p.ExitTime' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  System.DateTime {System.InvalidOperationException}
+       Handle  2368    System.IntPtr
        HandleCount 614 int
        HasExited   false   bool
        Id  4148    int
        MachineName "." string
+       MainModule  {System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (app.exe)}    System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule
+       MainWindowHandle    1771888 System.IntPtr
        MainWindowTitle "C:\\app.exe"   string
+       MaxWorkingSet   1413120 System.IntPtr
+       MinWorkingSet   204800  System.IntPtr
+       Modules {System.Diagnostics.ProcessModuleCollection}    System.Diagnostics.ProcessModuleCollection
        NonpagedSystemMemorySize    59684   int
        NonpagedSystemMemorySize64  59684   long
        PagedMemorySize 63553536    int
        PagedMemorySize64   63553536    long
        PagedSystemMemorySize   490456  int
        PagedSystemMemorySize64 490456  long
        PeakPagedMemorySize 69619712    int
        PeakPagedMemorySize64   69619712    long
        PeakVirtualMemorySize   386330624   int
        PeakVirtualMemorySize64 386330624   long
        PeakWorkingSet  91586560    int
        PeakWorkingSet64    91586560    long
        PriorityBoostEnabled    true    bool
        PriorityClass   Normal  System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass
        PrivateMemorySize   63553536    int
        PrivateMemorySize64 63553536    long
+       PrivilegedProcessorTime {00:00:20.7793332}  System.TimeSpan
        ProcessName "app"   string
+       ProcessorAffinity   255 System.IntPtr
        Responding  true    bool
        SessionId   2   int
+       StandardError   'p.StandardError' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' System.IO.StreamReader {System.InvalidOperationException}
+       StandardInput   'p.StandardInput' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' System.IO.StreamWriter {System.InvalidOperationException}
+       StandardOutput  'p.StandardOutput' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    System.IO.StreamReader {System.InvalidOperationException}
+       StartInfo   {System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo}   System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
+       StartTime   {10/5/2013 2:19:53 PM}  System.DateTime
        SynchronizingObject null    System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke
+       Threads {System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection}    System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection
+       TotalProcessorTime  {00:07:39.5633459}  System.TimeSpan
+       UserProcessorTime   {00:07:18.7840127}  System.TimeSpan
        VirtualMemorySize   378003456   int
        VirtualMemorySize64 378003456   long
        WorkingSet  88723456    int
        WorkingSet64    88723456    long
+       Static members      
-       Non-Public members      
+       base    {System.Diagnostics.Process (app)}  System.ComponentModel.Component {System.Diagnostics.Process}
        Associated  true    bool
        disposed    false   bool
        error   null    System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader
        ErrorDataReceived   null    System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler
        errorStreamReadMode undefined   System.Diagnostics.Process.StreamReadMode
        exitCode    259 int
        exited  false   bool
+       exitTime    {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime
        haveExitTime    false   bool
        haveMainWindow  true    bool
        havePriorityBoostEnabled    true    bool
        havePriorityClass   true    bool
        haveProcessHandle   true    bool
        haveProcessId   true    bool
        haveProcessorAffinity   true    bool
        haveResponding  false   bool
        haveWorkingSetLimits    true    bool
        isRemoteMachine false   bool
        m_processAccess 2035711 int
+       m_processHandle {Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle} Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle
        machineName "." string
        mainWindowHandle    1771888 System.IntPtr
        mainWindowTitle "C:\\app.exe"   string
        maxWorkingSet   1413120 System.IntPtr
        minWorkingSet   204800  System.IntPtr
+       modules {System.Diagnostics.ProcessModuleCollection}    System.Diagnostics.ProcessModuleCollection
        onExited    null    System.EventHandler
+       OperatingSystem {Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0}   System.OperatingSystem
+       operatingSystem {Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0}   System.OperatingSystem
        output  null    System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader
        OutputDataReceived  null    System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler
        outputStreamReadMode    undefined   System.Diagnostics.Process.StreamReadMode
        pendingErrorRead    false   bool
        pendingOutputRead   false   bool
        priorityBoostEnabled    true    bool
        priorityClass   Normal  System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass
        processId   4148    int
        processInfo {System.Diagnostics.ProcessInfo}    System.Diagnostics.ProcessInfo
        processorAffinity   255 System.IntPtr
        raisedOnExited  false   bool
        registeredWaitHandle    null    System.Threading.RegisteredWaitHandle
        responding  true    bool
        signaled    false   bool
        standardError   null    System.IO.StreamReader
        standardInput   null    System.IO.StreamWriter
        standardOutput  null    System.IO.StreamReader
-       startInfo   {System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo}   System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        Arguments   ""  string
        CreateNoWindow  false   bool
        Domain  ""  string
+       EnvironmentVariables    {System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionaryWithComparer}   System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary {System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionaryWithComparer}
        ErrorDialog false   bool
+       ErrorDialogParentHandle 0   System.IntPtr
        FileName    ""  string
        LoadUserProfile false   bool
+       Password    null    System.Security.SecureString
        RedirectStandardError   false   bool
        RedirectStandardInput   false   bool
        RedirectStandardOutput  false   bool
+       StandardErrorEncoding   null    System.Text.Encoding
+       StandardOutputEncoding  null    System.Text.Encoding
        UserName    ""  string
        UseShellExecute true    bool
        Verb    ""  string
        Verbs   {string[0]} string[]
        WindowStyle Normal  System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle
        WorkingDirectory    ""  string
+       Non-Public members      
        synchronizingObject null    System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke
-       threads {System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection}    System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection
-       base    {System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection}    System.Collections.ReadOnlyCollectionBase {System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection}
        Count   36  int
-       Non-Public members      
+       [System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection]    {System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection}    System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection
+       InnerList   Count = 36  System.Collections.ArrayList
+       list    Count = 36  System.Collections.ArrayList
        System.Collections.ICollection.IsSynchronized   false   bool
        System.Collections.ICollection.SyncRoot {object}    object
        waitHandle  null    System.Threading.WaitHandle
        watchForExit    false   bool
        watchingForExit false   bool
```

Comment: Does the program expose an API or COM interface? If so, you could try calling it and seeing if you get a valid response in a timely fashion. I'm not aware of any way you could accurately judge another programs state from the outside - and each type of problem would require a specific detection mechanism (infinite loop, OOM, modal dialogue, etc, etc)

Comment: API or COM, don't know, is there a easy way to find out?

Comment: In short, not really - for COM [you need to know](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681468/156755) and an Api could be exposed many different ways. That said, if you don't know about an Api, it probably doesn't have one

Answer (score 2):

```
Process[] procs;
procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(appName);
bool restartRequired = false;
foreach (Process proc in procs) {
    if (!proc.Responding) {
        restartRequired = true;
        proc.Kill();
        break;
    }
}

if (restartRequired) {
    Process procRun = new Process();
    procRun.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Winword.exe";
    procRun.Start();
}
```

Comment: This will detect if windows thinks the app is responding (usually, just that it has a message pump which is running), but won't catch all problems. That said, it's an improvement over the OP's approach so +1

Comment: Sounds nice, and if not complete at least safe. I'll try it out.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working in my case, the program is responding or it has `responding`=true, it's a cmd interface app and it has a error :  `Problem Event Name: APPCRASH ,   Fault Module Version: 8.0.7600.17267
  Fault Module Timestamp: 5131882e
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00429796
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.274.10
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789`

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways you can experiment with your app. Try the below two,

```
System.Reflection.Assembly app = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Windows\\ConsoleApp.exe");
Type[] types = app.GetTypes();
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Main", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (method != null)
    {
    tryAgain:

        try
        {
            method.Invoke(null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds if u wish..
            goto tryAgain;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

And,

```
void init()
{
    loadProcess();
}

void loadProcess()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\ConsoleApp.exe";
    prc.Exited += new EventHandler(prc_Exited);  // Event Handler when the process is exited. (Mostly not working 4 me)
    prc.Start();
}

void prc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadProcess();       
}
```

Comment: the prc.Exited won't work unfortunately :) the process object (`p`) shows it's still running.

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual case you're after is an APPCRASH caused by an unhandled exception you could set a custom app as the JIT debugger, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5hs4b7a6.aspx

Your custom/replacement JIT debugger will check if the crashed app is the one you are watching, if yes restart it, if no then pass to the real JIT debugger.